# routing to multiple component using same route but different path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

my application has a dropdown menu that has a list of tools and I want to redirect the user to the particular chosen tool but I don't what to create different routes for different tools cause this will be a tedious process and my routing component file will also be unimaginable longer.

do react have some way of connecting `<Link/>` with the `<Route />` via which I can redirect a user to different components depending upon the tool that a client choose but same route.

finally, a way of passing data from the Link to the route which can be utilized to specify the component name.

down below I have specified the path that I am using.

`<Route path="/webenv/:webenv/tools/:tool" component={tool} />`

Comment: You can create generic component that get `tool` variable from `useParams()` and then render from `switch (tool) {}`